# Unable to load profile in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add additional fields to the default User model. I had a look around the internet and done something like this:

Made a new model named UserProfile with the following in /UserProfile/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This is the only required field
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

    # The rest is completely up to you...
    favorite_band = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    favorite_cheese = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    lucky_number = models.IntegerField()
```

And added:

```
 AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "newSite.userprofile"
```

To the settings, I also added "UserProfile" to the INSTALLED_APPS as to run sqlall.

The only problem is when I try the following in the shell:

```
 >>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 >>> user = User.objects.get(username = "user01")
 >>> user.get_profile()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 367,in get_profile
     raise SiteProfileNotAvailable('Unable to load the profile '

SiteProfileNotAvailable: Unable to load the profile model, check AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE in your project settings
```

Any help to solve this problem is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really did create an app caled UserProfile and put the models.py there, then you should put

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "userprofile.userprofile"
```

into your `settings.py` file instead.

You should make your UserProfile folder lowercase: `userprofile`

Comment: Thanks, I changed the folder name to lowercase characters and it worked fine!

Comment: The second part, however, is case-insensitive.